# How do I get my IDE to provide the C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, netbeans, ide, gnu

I figured out how to get the correct and current version of GNU to be the target when compiling.

Now whenever I try to compile.. I get tons of errors that I'm assuming are related to the C++ libraries. I'm currently using NetBeans latest version on my MacBook with the latest install of Mountain Lion.

NetBeans shows a red line under the line:

```
#include <random>
```

saying that it cannot find the include file.

I get probably 50 lines of errors. I think it's because it can't detect libraries/headers included in c++? Here's part of the error message

```
main.cpp:46:31: error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ofstream&)'
main.cpp:46:31: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:114:0,
             from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/cwchar:46,
             from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/postypes.h:42,
             from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/iosfwd:42,
             from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/ios:39,
             from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/ostream:40,
             from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/iostream:40,
             from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/stdio.h:449:9: note: ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)
/usr/include/stdio.h:449:9: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/string:54:0,
```

I right clicked the project folder and hit "run" and it gives me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

"std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator   >::compare(char const*) const", referenced from:
      Ammunition::setElementData(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >) in Ammunition.o
      Armor::setElementData(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >) in Armor.o
      Consumable::setElementData(std::__1::basic_string,  std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string,  std::__1::allocator >) in Consumable.o
      Creature::setElementData(std::__1::basic_string,  std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string,   std::__1::allocator >) in Creature.o
      Entity::setElementData(std::__1::basic_string,   std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string,   std::__1::allocator >) in Entity.o
      Item::setElementData(std::__1::basic_string,   std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string,   std::__1::allocator >) in Item.o
      parseElement(std::__1::basic_istream >&,   std::__1::vector >&, XMLSerializable*)  in parser.o
      ...
   "std::_*1::*_vector_base_common::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      _*ZNSt3*_16vectorIP4ItemNS_9allocatorIS2_EEE6assignIPS2_EENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeES9_S9_ in Creature.o
      std::_*1::vector >::allocate(unsigned long) in Creature.o
      void std::*_1::vector,   std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator > > >::__push_back_slow_path, std::__1::allocator > const&>(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&) in Entity.o
      void std::_*1::vector >::*_push_back_slow_path(XMLSerializable* const&) in parser.o
      void std::_*1::vector   >::*_push_back_slow_path(Creature* const&) in CreatureFactory.o
       std::_*1::vector,   std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in   CreatureFactory.o
      std::*_1::vector >::__append(unsigned long, Tile const&)   in DungeonLevel.o
      ...

Do you know why this is happening? And is it even related to the libraries?

Comment: Start at the beginning of the error. What's on line 46 of main.cpp?

Comment: It's literally a blank line

Comment: I right clicked the project folder and hit "run" to make sure it was running the correct files. I've added what it said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your function call is wrong.

1. You are currently calling a version of `getline` which works with `FILE` pointers, which is not what you intended. That's the only one the compiler found, based on the headers included.
2. You are probably trying to extract a line from an input stream, correct? So try [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/). Make sure you `#include <string>`.
3. Also, you probably don't want to be calling `getline` on an output stream...

--- Edit ---

The errors you've added look like your library paths are not set correctly... sorry this is hard to fix without having access to the system, hopefully someone else will be able to help you. Good luck.

Comment: That line is empty, lol I swear. I just uploaded the same code to my schools SSH and it compiled and ran perfectly fine. I don't get how it runs 100% fine on the server but when I download the same state of the code, I get nonstop errors

Comment: I got lucky and after running a terminal command to show my hidden files, I found the old directory that had all of the libraries and plugins and such. So I simply copied all of the new files, selecting to overwrite the older ones, and set the compiler path back to how it was. Now the only problem is how my makefile compiles/links everything. I'm so close!

Comment: Keep at it! Then you will be able to answer other people's questions about NetBeans :-)

Comment: Thanks. If you're familiar with makefiles, feel free to help me solve the last problem I'm having haha: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272046/why-do-i-have-to-double-run-make-to-fully-compile-my-program-gnu-c