# Why do I have to double run make to fully compile my program? GNU c++

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, makefile, gnu

Im terrible with understanding what goes on behind the scenes when running programs.

On my schools server, I just use gcc and pretty much the same code every time I need to make a makefile lol.

I downloaded my program to debug it in NetBeans and after hours/days.. I finally ALMOST have everything working.

After looking at a few posts on here and other sites, I saw that for some reason I need to use g++ instead of gcc to compile since I'm using a MacBook. Which I don't really understand.. But if I change gcc to g++ and run this line in my makefile:

### Edit:

```
 g++ -c $< -o $@ -std=c++0x -lstdc++
```

I get an error. But if I remove "-std=c++0x" and run make again.. Everything is good to go.

But if I run my "make clean" I have to do it over again..

Will this mess everything up when I put the program back on my schools server? Or should it be fine as long as I have a makefile on the server that is different from the makefile on my MacBook?

Can someone help expelling why this is happening and how I could possibly fix it?

Here's my makefile the first time I run make:

```
OBJECTS = Ammunition.o Armor.o Consumable.o 
HEADERS = Ammunition.h Armor.h Consumable.h 

all: Jhack

%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    g++ -c $< -o $@ -std=c++0x

Jhack: $(OBJECTS) main.o
    g++ -o Jhack $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o Jhack

run: Jhack
    ./Jhack
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, what error do you get, and what compiler are you using? `-std=c++0x` and `-lstdc++` are not interchangeable.

Comment: What the name of your makefile?

Comment: @juanchopanza GNU/g++

Comment: @Justin OK, just checking you hadn't called it Jhack or something, people do to all sorts of strange things. So you are saying that when you run make clean, your makefile gets deleted? Or have I completely misread the question?

Comment: @john totally understandable. When I run clean, the makefile is fine. But I run it with the headers line as: "g++ -c $< -o $@ -std=c++0x" and I get errors. Then I simply change it (without cleaning again) to: "g++ -c $< -o $@ -lstdc++" and it finishes compiling. Then I just run my executable and everything works fine lol.

Comment: Sorry I said that wrong. If I have the headers line with "g++ -c $< -o $@ -std=c++0x -lstdc++" I get an error. But if I remove "-std=c++0x" and run make again.. Everythings good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for Linux GNU C compilers, **gcc** is a C compiler whereas **g++** is a C++ compiler. Which means when you compile with gcc, all your error messages are basically saying, "I don't know what all this strange syntax is."

Your school isn't using a Linux server, or "gcc" there may be a link to a c++ compiler.  Or the core make rules are replacing your compiler choice with g++.

I don't think there's all that much you need to worry about in this regard.  Just remember the difference, and possibly replace gcc and g++ with a macro in your makefile.

As for the -std option, that's choosing which version of the C++ standard you want to compile against.  Since some of your code requires 2011 C++ standard, you need to specify that with your -std option.  If you look at your g++ man pages, it should tell you what options are supported.

You can try `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`

Any of those should give you the functionality you require.  Based on what I've searched for, you don't need to specify `-std=stdc++` since *i think* that's included by g++ by default.

Comment: GCC became the "Gnu Compiler **collection** quite a while ago. It knows that `.cpp` is a C++ file, and is compiled as such. Similarly, `.c` is a C file and compiled as such. `-x <language>` overrides it, but the default is `-x none`, auto-select.

Comment: @serge Ok that makes more sense. I tried all 3 of those however and I I'm still getting errors. The Frustration of Programming.

Comment: @MSalters That's what I thought too, except that I never could successfully build cpp code with `gcc` where `g++` works.  I just now realised that gcc doesn't include the ``stdc++`` library, so it's not passing the correct library requirements to the linker.  I needed to add ``-lstdc++`` to the gcc line.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably usign an old, experimental version of GCC. "ConceptGCC" from the comments, and the `-std=c++0x` flag tell me so. Modern GCC variants would use `-std=c++11` instead.

You never *need* to use g++ instead of gcc. It's just a convenience, so you don't need to pass all gcc options required to compile C++. In particular, `-lstdc++` is implied by g++.

Since you're using a rather unusual "ConceptGCC" package, I'd suggest you replace it by the normal GCC version 4.8.0.

To debug what make is trying to do, run `make -n`. You can then run these commands manually to see precisely what happens.

Comment: "Modern" as in post GCC 4.7.1. `-std=c++11` wasn't added that long ago.

Comment: Hmm. I have 4.7.1. I tried changing it back to gcc instead of g++ and It shows a bunch more errors?

Comment: @justin: Then ask a new question. Please include actual command line and resulting error text.

Comment: @Justin: Apply common sense, most of those errors are probably similar. The error in your comment (This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard...must be enabled with the -std=c++11...) is a good example of an error that should have been in the original question. `std::mt19937` indeed is new in the ISO C++11 Standard, which is why you need `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah that makes sense. But every way I try to add that to my makfile, I get more errors. I can't get the syntax right. Oh well. I give up. I've wasted too much time on this just so I can debug my code. It's just wasting everyones time. Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Justin, I don't know what `std=c++0x` does (I looked it up but I don't know what "experimental features" are possibly being affected...), but if removing it helps, then just remove it.

What you have described sounds to me like some objects require the `std=c++0x` flag and some won't build with it. Would you try just removing the flag, cleaning and then rebuilding?

Worst case - remove the variable rule and write three different rules for each of your object files.

Comment: I think it's to let me do "this->" when pointing to an object. I think I've tried that but I'll do it again really quick. Well I actually have 18 object files, but I took most of them out for simplicity.

Comment: Here's the error: /opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
In file included from Creature.h:5:0,
                 from Creature.cpp:1:
DungeonLevel.h:12:45: error: 'std::mt19937' has not been declared
DungeonLevel.h:28:30: error: '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list....

And a few more lines

Comment: Ok, so you definitely need it for at least Creature.o. What error do you get when you include the flag? Hopefully it affects a different object's build.

Comment: Tons of warnings. And something about not found in architecture. Then this:   "typeinfo for Item", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Ammunition in Ammunition.o
      typeinfo for Armor in Armor.o
      typeinfo for Consumable in Consumable.o
      typeinfo for Gold in Gold.o
      typeinfo for Weapon in Weapon.o
      ItemFactory::ItemFactory() in ItemFactory.o
      ItemFactory::ItemFactory() in ItemFactory.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I downloaded the ConceptGCC package. Do you know where I need to put that to get it to work?

Comment: Wow that makes no sense to me, sorry. I guess try writing the makefile with separate lines for each object, including the flag for Creature and not for Ammunition, Armor etc. Sorry I can't solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Also no, I don't know what ConceptGCC is

Comment: No problem. No one has been able to figure out what's been going on with my computer. And ConceptGCC is the package that has the std=c++0x. Thanks for your help